# How reproduce multiple plot (ggplot) with for iteration in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am not very skilled with the ggplot package, but I would like to know the reason for the following error. I am looking to graph through an iteration (for) several ggplot graphs.

The names of the columns come as follows:

```
> head(colnames(basefinal))

[1] "1. Nombre de la empresa"                                  
[2] "2.Municipio de ubicación de la Empresa"                   
[3] "3. ¿Qué rol desempeña usted dentro de la Empresa?"        
[4] "4. El tipo de Sociedad de la Empresa familiar es: *"      
[5] "5.¿Cuál es el número de empleados de la Empresa familiar?"
[6] "6. La actividad principal de la Empresa familiar es:"
```

The iteration code is:

```
for (nm in names(basefinal)) 
{
    ggplot(basefinal, aes_string(parse(nm))) + 
       geom_bar(fill="sienna1",aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
       theme_classic() + 
       labs(y = "Porcentaje de empresas (%)", x= 'Rol dentro de la empresa') + 
       scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + 
       coord_flip() + 
       ggtitle(nm)
}
```

Show this error:

```
cannot open file '1. Nombre de la empresa': No such file or directoryError in file(filename, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

Comment: It should be `parse(text = nm)` not `parse(nm)`. Otherwise `parse` will think `"1. Nombre de la empresa"` is a file name

Comment: FYI, the return value from a `for` loop is always `NULL` (try `(for(i in 1:3) i)`). Unlike base graphics, `ggplot(...)` does not have the side-effect of showing an image; a plot is only shown when the object is either (1) dumped on the console, called directly; or (2) directly or indirectly through `ggplot2::print.ggplot`, which is called when you dump an object (e.g., `gg <- ggplot(...); gg`) or explicitly call `print(gg)`. In your case, if you want it printed from within the `for` loop, capture the value then `print` it.

Comment: OK, but it happens that I throw another error ```Error in parse (text = names (basefinal)): <text>: 1: 4: unexpected symbol
1: 1. Nombre``` Or, What other way to call the variable could you use?

Comment: BTW, no need for `parse`, just use `ggplot(basefinal, aes_string(nm)) + ...`, and then take a look at some of the points in my answer on ways you might be able to improve this process.

Comment: OK,thank you very much. He has been very kind man, I have understood everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some suggestions for what I think you're doing here.

First, I don't have your data, so I'll make some up. My `q1` is similar to your `1. Nombre de la empresa`.

```r
set.seed(42)
basefinal <- data.frame(
  q1 = sample(letters[1:3], size=100, replace=TRUE),
  q2 = sample(letters[1:3], size=100, replace=TRUE),
  q3 = sample(letters[1:3], size=100, replace=TRUE))
head(basefinal)
#   q1 q2 q3
# 1  c  b  c
# 2  c  a  b
# 3  a  a  c
# 4  c  b  b
# 5  b  c  a
# 6  b  c  b
```

My first thought is that you don't need to `parse` things:

```r
for (nm in names(basefinal)) {
  ggplot(basefinal, aes_string(nm)) +
    geom_bar(fill="sienna1", aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
    theme_classic() +
    labs(y = "Porcentaje de empresas (%)", x= 'Rol dentro de la empresa') +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
    coord_flip() +
    ggtitle(nm)
}
```

One "problem" with this is the way that `ggplot` plots work. With base graphics, everything works in implied side-effect by altering the current "dev" (graphic canvas). In contrast, `ggplot` plots do nothing to the current dev until you explicitly do something. By design, this is when you explicitly tell it to do so by one of:

1. Call `ggplot(...) + ...` explicitly on the console. This implicitly returns an object of class `c("gg", "ggplot")`, and the console finds an S3 method to use to `print` it. In this case, it finds `ggplot2:::print.ggplot`.
2. Store it into a variable, perhaps `gg <- ggplot(..) + ...`, and then dump this object on the console (type `gg` on the `>` console prompt). This finds the `print` method from number 1.
3. Explicitly print it with `print(gg)` (which finds `ggplot2:::print.ggplot2`, even if you don't to look for it or where to find it ... it is not exported).

So in the `for` loop, you create a series of `ggplot` objects but do nothing with them, so they are silently discarded. Further, `for` loops never return anything (other than `NULL`), regardless of what is in the loop. So if you want to present all of these plots in rapid succession, you should capture the object and print it.

```r
for (nm in names(basefinal)) {
  gg <- ggplot(basefinal, aes_string(nm)) +
    geom_bar(fill="sienna1", aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
    theme_classic() +
    labs(y = "Porcentaje de empresas (%)", x= 'Rol dentro de la empresa') +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
    coord_flip() +
    ggtitle(nm)
  print(gg)
}
```

This does not let you really pause and look at any of them, other than the last plot (since in R and RStudio, the plot window normally stays up). If you want to be able to look at them individually, you might want to capture *all* of the grobs (**gr**aphic **ob**jects).

```r
ggs <- list()
for (nm in names(basefinal)) {
  gg <- ggplot(basefinal, aes_string(nm)) +
    geom_bar(fill="sienna1", aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
    theme_classic() +
    labs(y = "Porcentaje de empresas (%)", x= 'Rol dentro de la empresa') +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
    coord_flip() +
    ggtitle(nm)
  ggs[[nm]] <- gg
}
print(ggs[[1]]) # or print(ggs[[ names(basefinal)[3] ]])
```

[image: first ggplot]

I'm a fan of R's `apply` functions, however, and this is more efficiently coded as

```r
ggs <- sapply(names(basefinal), function(nm) {
  ggplot(basefinal, aes_string(nm)) +
    geom_bar(fill="sienna1", aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
    theme_classic() +
    labs(y = "Porcentaje de empresas (%)", x= 'Rol dentro de la empresa') +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
    coord_flip() +
    ggtitle(nm)
}, simplify = FALSE)
```

(Same ability to now view any of the grobs in `ggs` as-desired.)

---

But wait, there's more.

I think data like this might benefit from faceting, one thing that `ggplot2` makes somewhat easy. Unfortunately, your data is in a "wide" layout and `ggplot2` prefers "long" formats. Let's reshape this:

```r
tidyr::pivot_longer(basefinal, everything())
# # A tibble: 300 x 2
#    name  value
#    <chr> <fct>
#  1 q1    c    
#  2 q2    b    
#  3 q3    c    
#  4 q1    c    
#  5 q2    a    
#  6 q3    b    
#  7 q1    a    
#  8 q2    a    
#  9 q3    c    
# 10 q1    c    
# # ... with 290 more rows
```

We can now combine all questions into one plot. This can be arranged either as a grid (various columns) or just wrapping. Examples:

```r
ggplot(tidyr::pivot_longer(basefinal, everything()),
       aes(value)) +
  geom_bar(fill="sienna1", aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(y = "Porcentaje de empresas (%)", x= 'Rol dentro de la empresa') +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(~ name)
```

[image: ggplot facet grid 1]

```r
... + facet_grid(name ~ .)
```

[image: ggplot facet grid 2]

```r
... + facet_wrap("name", ncol = 2)
```

[image: ggplot wrap]

No loop required, and everything is plotted on the same scale. (They can have individual scales if you'd like, but sometimes it can be best -- less-biasing -- to show them with the same axes.)